# python struct pack displaying ascii

Tags: python, struct

When using

```
import struct
struct.pack(">H",31001)
```

The output is `'y\x19'`, when I expected `'\x79\x19'`.  I know that \x79 is y in ASCII, but is the information the same?  Why is that one byte impacted when the other one is not?  I am trying to send a modbus command and am wondering if that is causing a communication issue. I am new to modbus and am having trouble diagnosing why the slave will not respond to the master.

Comment: The information is the same, Python's `repr()` output just displays printable ASCII characters where it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the result of the `repr()` function, which the Python interactive interpreter uses on all results that are not `None`.

Python string contents are shown using ASCII *text* for any character that is printable, `\r`, `\n` and `\t` for ASCII carriage return, newline and tab characters respectively, and `\xhh` hex escapes for the rest.

And yes, `'\x79'` is the exact same byte as `'y'`:

```
>>> 'y' == '\x79'
True
```

but when producing the representation, Python simply prefers to show you the printable ASCII character:

```
>>> '\x79'
'y'
```

You could encode the string to `'hex'` if you want to see *all* codepoints represented as hexadecimal:

```
>>> 'y\x19'.encode('hex')
'7919'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the information is the same.  The struct is a sequence of bytes, and printable bytes are displayed as the character they represent.  The reason one is shown in escape form and the other isn't is that one is a printable ASCII character and the other isn't.