# Show hex value for all bytes, even when ASCII characters are present

Tags: python

In Python (3) at least, if a binary value has an ASCII representation, it is shown instead of the hexadecimal value. For instance, the binary value of `67` which is ASCII `C` is show as follows:

```
bytes([67]) # b'C'
```

Whereas for binary values without ASCII representations, they are shown in hex. I.E.

```
b'\x0f'
```

Is there a way to force Python to show the binary values in their binary-hex form (if this is what it is called), even when there are ASCII representations?

**Edit:** By this I mean, something that starts with `b'\x'`,. This would make debugging easier when you are looking for specific bytes to be printed for instance.

Thanks

Comment: @BrenBarn I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. This question is asking about how to get a hex-for-everything as a repr (or some other string transformation) while the other question/answer mainly supposes the difference and addresses the equivalency thereof.

Comment: @user2864740: The answer, though, includes a way to display hex values of all bytes.

Comment: I did see that question, but I was thinking along the same lines.  In that question the accepted answer does a good job of explaining that they are the same and why they are printed different, but does not explain how to essentially "turn off" repr's ASCII formatting. I know they are the same, but during debugging, it is more difficult to continually convert.  Even using `.encode('hex')` as that answer mentions does not format the characters the same (i.e. prefixing them with `\x`

Comment: @Startec: If it's important to you to specifically have the `\x`, you should probably edit your question to say that (and to explain why).

Comment: Yes, but that answer shows hex values, not binary representations...Which are indeed different. `'7919'` vs `b'\x79\x19'`

Comment: Note that you're confusing between Python the language and the REPL. Perhaps there **is** a Python REPL that outputs every string in its binary format representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific means of requiring any particular formatting (like `\x`) for a byte string.  If you really need specific formatting, you could use something like the `.hex()` solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264261/python-struct-pack-displaying-ascii), but wrap it with other code to insert the formatting you need.  Another useful tool is the `hex` builtin function.  For instance, if you want `\x`:

```
>>> x = bytes([67, 128])
>>> print(''.join(r'\x'+hex(letter)[2:] for letter in x))
\x43\x80
```

If you just need to be able to visually distinguish the bytes, using `hex` by itself may work for you (it uses `0x` instead of `\x`):

```
>>> print(''.join(hex(letter) for letter in x))
0x430x80
```

There is not a way to make this the default behavior for byte strings.  Whatever you do, you're going to have to write code that specifies the display format you want; you can't make Python automatically display printable bytes as `\x` escapes.

Comment: This will fail however for characters with a hex value < x10 though. if you do `x = bytes([10,67,128])` you will get `\xa\x43\x80` which isn't valid it needs to be `\x0a\x43\x80` I would recommend changing to this: `print(''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(letter) for letter in x))`

Answer (score 5):

After installing my package [`all-escapes`](https://github.com/wimglenn/all-escapes) there will be a new codec available for this usage.

```
>>> b = bytes([10,67,128])
>>> print(b.decode("all-escapes"))
\x0a\x43\x80
```