# Python bytes seem different than it should be in socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I've been trying to learn socket programming and my aim is to send request from client to the server, also send back a response from server to client despite client's request.
In the code, i am trying to send \x02\x03\x35\x36\x37\x01\x00\05\x02\x75 and \x02\x05\x01\x35\x36\x01\x01\05\x02\x76 datas but in my output i see \x02\x03567\x01\x00\x05\x02u and \x02\x05\x0156\x01\x01\x05\x02v instead of them. Am i doing something wrong?
Here are my codes:

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1236))

s.listen(5)
print("Waiting for connection...")

server_message = b"\x02\x05\x01\x35\x36\x01\x01\05\x02\x76"

while True:
    clientsocket, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"Successfully connected with client from {addr}", addr)

    client_message = clientsocket.recv(1024)            # Get request from the client.
    print("Request from the Client:", client_message)

    if client_message.__eq__(b"\x02\x03\x35\x36\x37\x01\x00\05\x02\x75"): # If request is appropriate for response then;
        clientsocket.send(server_message)           # Send response to the client.
        print("Response to the Client:", server_message)

    clientsocket.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1236))

client_message = b"\x02\x03\x35\x36\x37\x01\x00\05\x02\x75"

try:
    s.send(client_message)      # Send request to the server.

    server_message = s.recv(1024)       # Get response from the server.

    print("Request to the Server:", client_message)
    print("Response from the Server:", server_message)

    s.close()

except socket.error as error_message:
    print("Server is not working", error_message)
```

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568245/show-hex-value-for-all-bytes-even-when-ascii-characters-are-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, and they only *seem* different. As you will quickly see see if you do this:

```
>>> version1 = b"\x02\x03\x35\x36\x37\x01\x00\05\x02\x75"
>>> version2 = b'\x02\x03567\x01\x00\x05\x02u'
>>> version1==version2
True
```

The reason is because `\x35` is the byte value of the character `5`, and when Python displays bytestrings it renders any printable character as that character, and if it is not printable but there is a string escape, then it renders it as the string escape, so `\x0d` which is a carriage return will appear as `\r`, and it only renders a byte as a hex escape as a last resort. There are various reasons for this, but one of the most obvious is that bytestrings often contain character data, and `b'Hello world'` is friendlier than `b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64'`.