# Is there way to print python3 bytes as hex string without ascii conversion and without using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

```
buf = b"\x00\xdd\x41"

print(str(buf))
```

gives '\x00\xddA'.

I need '\x00\xdd\x41'.

Basically [Show hex value for all bytes, even when ASCII characters are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568245/show-hex-value-for-all-bytes-even-when-ascii-characters-are-present) without the loop or external module. Just want to know if this is possible with any built-in Python3 function.

My current code is `"".join(["\\x" + hex(x)[2:] for x in buf])`.
I am trying to find a built-in alternative to it, if it exists in Python 3 or any simpler alternative to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show hex value for all bytes, even when ASCII characters are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568245/show-hex-value-for-all-bytes-even-when-ascii-characters-are-present)

Comment: In what way does that question and its answers fail to answer your question?

Comment: It involves writing a loop. I want avoid writing a loop for a basic conversion. Just want to know if there's something built-in alternative to `"".join(["\\x"+hex(x) for x in buf])`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function that does what you want.

What do you consider "not a loop"?  There's a hidden loop in the non-Python implementation of `re.sub` below, but no *Python* loop.

```py
import re

def hexify(s):
    return "b'" + re.sub(r'.', lambda m: f'\\x{ord(m.group(0)):02x}', buf.decode('latin1')) + "'"

buf = b'\x00\xdd\x41'
print(hexify(buf))
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\xdd\x41'
```