# Python bytesarray

Tags: python, hex

```
    data = bytearray()
    data.append(0xCC)
    data.append(0x00)
    data.append(0x44)
    data.append(0x01)
    data.append(0x00)
    data.append(0xDD)
    data.append(0xEE)
    data.append(0x01)
```

my expectation is bytearray(b'\xcc\x00\x44\x01\x00\xdd\xee\x01')
but real value is bytearray(b'\xcc\x00**D**\x01\x00\xdd\xee\x01')

why D is added after 0x00?

Pleas, help me.

Comment: `0x44` is `D` .

Comment: I did edit my question, I expect b'\xcc\x00\x44\x01\x00\xdd\xee\x01')

Comment: Its the same thing.

Comment: `data.hex()` will give `'cc00440100ddee01'` - i.e. it will show hex codes for printable and non-printable chars alike. Whereas just printing the bytearray renders printable characters with their ASCII values, e.g. `\0x44` -> `D`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `data.append(0x44)` you are adding the byte `44` into the bytesarray. However since the byte 44 is the capital letter D in the ascii table, python will show it as `D` instead of `\x44`. This is because python tries to show byte values as their ascii form instead of the hex form if possible. Do not fret, the value `\x44` is still stored in the data bytesarray as `\x44` only that printing it out shows its ascii form.

If you really want to output it as hex refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568245/show-hex-value-for-all-bytes-even-when-ascii-characters-are-present)

- Jerome :)

Answer (score 0):

When printing a `bytes` or `bytearray` object in Python, any bytes that are printable ASCII characters will be printed as ASCII. It's only unprintable characters that are printed using their escape sequences.

```py
>>> bytes([
...     0x42,  # ASCII 'B'
...     0x10,  # unprintable '\x10'
...     0x0A,  # newline '\n'
... ])
b'B\x10\n'
```